# How do I use Typescript definition (typings) files installed via NuGet in VS2017?

Tags: typescript, nuget, visual-studio-2017, typescript-typings, definitelytyped

I'm a little unsure on how I would go about using a typescript definition file that has been installed via NuGet in 2017. I'd like to use the 'modal' Bootstrap Jquery method on a JQuery Selector in order to show a modal popup box, but the TypeScript compiler does not recognise the '.modal' method, even though the Bootstrap definition file has been installed correctly.

[image]

Even though the definitelytyped definition files have been installed via NuGet, the typescript compiler doesn't seem to be finding them.

Are there any steps I need to take in order for the compiler to recognise the definition files as being installed?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like nuget isn't supported any longer for installing DefinitelyTyped definitions for Asp.Net Core.

References :

[Visual Studio Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/40192/cant-add-definitely-typed-nuget-packages-to-net-co.html)

[DefinitelyTyped Github page](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped#npm)